# What format for a Python package's README on github?

Tags: python, github, package, packaging

The Python `distutils` in `setup.py` looks for `README` and `README.txt` in the root directory of a package. github recognizes formats like `README.md` and `README.rst`. How do I write one formatted root level README file that satisfies both?

The only suggestion I've seen up here is to run [Pandoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718767/have-the-same-readme-both-in-markdown-and-restructuredtext) to covert between the formats. I'd like to avoid adding an extra build step if possible.

Is there some way to tell `distutils` "Use my README.rst"?

Alternately, are there any bad repercussions of ignoring this warning when I run `python setup.py sdist`?

```
warning: sdist: standard file not found: should have one of README, README.txt
```

PS. I'm using `distutils.core` because Google leads me [here](http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html). Is that out of date?

Comment: `ln -s README.md README` ? As markdown source is "human friendly" that might be sufficient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer is to use `setuptools` instead of `distutils.core`. If you follow the [setuptools instructions](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html) you can see how to make your default README an .rst file.