# Convert markdown to reStructuredtest?

Tags: markdown, pandoc, restructuredtext

How can I convert a file named `index.md` into a reStructuredText file`index.rst` without manual editing or anything?

How about vice-verse?

What is the general syntax of such changes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Have the same README both in Markdown and reStructuredText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10718767/have-the-same-readme-both-in-markdown-and-restructuredtext)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`pandoc --from=markdown --to=rst --output=index.rst index.md`

For the reverse you can try pretty much the same thing

`pandoc --from=rst --to=markdown --output=README.md README.rst`

The general syntax is

`pandoc --from={type} --to={type} --output={filename} {input-filename}`

Answer (score 2):

There is a quicker syntax if you have the right file extensions:

```
pandoc -s README.md -o README.rst
```

Where `-s` stands for source and `-o` for output.