# How to automatically add the absolute path of an image to markdown

Tags: python, markdown, restructuredtext

I'm trying to convert markdown to restructuredtext. markdown has a picture with a relative path, how to automatically add an absolute path instead of a relative path?

This is my code

```py
import m2r

def convert(md_file):
    with open(md_file, mode='r') as r_file:
        text = r_file.read()
    return m2r.convert(text=text)
```

Comment: You could use pathlib.Path(x).resolve() to get the absolute path to a file. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513056/how-to-get-absolute-path-of-a-pathlib-path-object

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30952995/convert-markdown-to-restructuredtest